# How to reduce depoyment time for RDS instance via Terraform?

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, amazon-rds

```
resource "aws_db_instance" "mydb1_mishal2" {
  allocated_storage        = 20 # gigabytes
  backup_retention_period  = 7   # in days
  db_subnet_group_name     = "${var.rds_public_subnet_group}"
  engine                   = "mysql"
  engine_version           = "5.7"
  identifier               = "dbmishalsecond"
  instance_class           = "db.t2.micro"
  multi_az                 = false
  name                     = "mydbmishalsecond"
  parameter_group_name     = "default.mysql5.7" # if you have tuned it
  password                 = "mishal12345" #"${trimspace(file("${path.module}/secrets/mydb1-password.txt"))}"
  port                     = 3306
  publicly_accessible      = true
  storage_encrypted        = false # you should always do this
  storage_type             = "gp2"
  username                 = "mydb1"
  #vpc_security_group_ids   = ["${aws_security_group.mydb1.id}"]
}
```

I am using the above code to deploy a RDS instance in AWS. But it is taking a lot of time to deploy. Logs below:

[Deployment logs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NOhVQ.png)

How can I reduce the deployment time or is it necessary evil?

Comment: It's so slow... take 10 to 15 mins... you can't reduce that time :(

Comment: You can't do anything from Terraform about the time it takes for an AWS RDS instance to spin up, although 5.5 mins does seem longer than I'd expect. How long does it take to create an instance with the same spec if you do it interactively in AWS console?

Comment: If you set `backup_retention_period` to 0 it will provision much faster. But obviously you will not have any automated backups, only manual.

Answer (score 0):

You can't really do anything about changing how long the RDS takes to become available except that multi-az DBs do take longer to start. But that's not really something you want to consider for startup time. You should consider your availability requirements for that parameter.